# How does android:rotationX and android:rotationY in XML actually work?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The function's parameters are float as stated in the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation) but then why does the following not work:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="4sp"
        android:layout_height="280sp"
        android:background="#F44336"
        android:rotationX="45.0"
        android:id="@+id/Dstrike1"/>
```

This just displays the original line in the centre of the parent view.
[image: Screenshot of the display]

Although to obtain a diagonal line on the screen android.animation can be used, is there a simpler method?

Comment: please run your app on device, I noticed that rotation may not be seen on Preview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public static final int rotationX
```

> Added in API level 11 .rotation of the view around the x axis, in
>   degrees.

You did't get it on **Preview section** .When you will run the app you will see this at the VM.